# Get value from dynamically generated textboxes to XML

Tags: c#, xml

I added 89 textboxes dynamically. I want to get the value of the textboxes to xml. I can add the textboxes just fine the problem is I cant get the values on those dynamically
added textboxes.

For example i want to get value from textBox1 to the node "F1" in XML ,from textBox2 to node "F2" in XML.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    XmlNodeList xnList;
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string dosyayolu = Application.StartupPath + "\\coupling.xml";
    doc.Load(dosyayolu);

    if (globaller.hangimenu == "TWT1")
    {
        xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/coup/TWT1");
    }
    else
    {
        xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/coup/TWT2");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 89; i++)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            xn["F" + (i + 1).ToString()].InnerText = "k";
            // xn["F1"].InnerText = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }

    doc.Save(dosyayolu);
}
```

Comment: You can add the text boxes to a parent control and the iterate through it's childs. If you know that control will contain only text boxes, then it shouldn't give any problem.

Comment: Make a collection of TextBoxes and get the required one by index.

Comment: you can try a reflection hack, but not recommended. `xn["F" + (i + 1).ToString()].InnerText = (string)typeof(TextBox).GetProperty("Text").GetValue(GetType().GetField("textBox" + (i + 1).ToString(), BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(this), null);` this assumes that you have the textboxes as members i.e. textBox1 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the extension `ChildrenOfType<T>()`.
Assuming that `grid` is the parent of all your TextBoxes..

```
var textBoxes= grid.ChildrenOfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < 89; i++)
{
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
        xn["F" + (i + 1).ToString()].InnerText = "k";
        xn["F1"].InnerText = textBoxes[ i ].Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm guessing your textboxes are of name textBox1, textBox2, .... also your xml nodes start on F1 instead of F2 so i altered the For loop a bit

```
for (int i = 1; i < 90; i++)
  {
      foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
      {
          // this if textboxes on form, yourUserControlName if it is under a usercontrol
          var tb = (TextBox)this.Controls["textBox" + i];
          xn["F" + i].InnerText = tb.Text;

      }
  }
```

Edited in favor of comment of Hassan Nisar

Comment: Upvoted. Seems right. Either use `this` or `ParentControlName` instead of `yourFormOrControlName`. I guess ToString() for `i` is not required, it will be converted to string automatically.

Comment: Edited; pointed to the usercontrolname instead of this because it could be a usercontrol under a form

Comment: Your reference was right. Actually my comment was pointing out same thing, for understanding of OP. Thanks for updates though.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
//create
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
for(int i=0;i<89;i++)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    sp.Children.Add(tb);
}

//get
foreach(TextBox tb in sp.Children)
{

}
```

or you can add all the textboxs to a list,and get them from list by index